# Understanding the `parent` parameter in resolver methods while using Graphql python

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I have been trying to wrap my head around using **parent** in Graphql. Would like someone to give me their own understanding of it as well as resolver methods in all. I have also read the **docs**.

```
class Person(ObjectType):

    # First_name is a field with a resolver that fetches data in our schema
    first_name = String()
    last_name = String()

    def resolve_full_name(parent, info):
        return f"{parent.first_name} {parent.last_name}"
```

Answer (score 0):

So Parent actually refers to the value object after the resolver has run and by default it's set to None. Refer to [this](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/objecttypes/)